# How to detect PizzaMarker

Tags: opencv, feature-detection

did somebody tried to find a pizzamarker like this one with "only" OpenCV so far?

[image: PizzaMarker01]

I was trying to detect this one but couldn't get good results so far. I do not know where this marker is in picture (no ROI is possible), the marker will be somewhere in the room (different ligthning effects) and not faceing orthoonal towards us. What I want - the corners and later the orientation of this marker extracted with the corners but first of all only the 5Corners. (up, down, left, right, center)

I was trying so far: threshold, noiseclearing, find contours but nothing realy helped for a good result. Chessboards or square markers are normaly found because of their (parallel) lines- i guess this can't help me here...

What is an easy way to find those markers? 
How would you start? 
Use other colorformat like HSV?

A step-by-step idea or tutorial would be realy helpfull. Cause i couldn't find tuts at the net. Maybe this marker isn't called pizzamarker -> does somebody knows the real name?

thx for help

Comment: Do you have an example image of the marker in a room? I realise you ask specifically for an OpenCV solution, but if you would be happy with a more general algorithm you might get some good responses on dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - thank you for all of your help. 
It seems that several methods are usefull. Some more or less time expansive.
For me it was the easiest with a template matching but not with the same marker. 
I used only a small part of it...

[image]

this can be found 5 times(4 times negative and one positive) in this new marker:

[image]

now I use only the 4 most negatives Points and the most positive and got my 5 points that I finaly wanted. To make this more sure, I check if they are close to each other and will do a cornerSubPix().

Answer (score 1):

You can train and use cvHaarDetectObjects to detect the marker using VJ.
Probably not the fastest method but it should work.
You can find more info on object detection methods using OpenCV here: [http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/object_detection.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20120706062114/http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/object_detection.html)

Comment: Yes this cascade template matching could be possible but seems very circumstantial. But thank you - if i don't find something better i will try it.

Comment: i will do try this today - it seems best thing to find the binary image in a binary(with threshold) image. The best match will give me the center of my roi and then i will try edge Detection.

Comment: Link is dead. Archive.org link: https://web.archive.org/web/20120706062114/http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/object_detection.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need something which can operate in real-time I'd go down the edge detection route and look for intersecting lines like [these guys did](http://vesta.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/opus/volltexte/2011/3095/pdf/6.pdf). Seems fast and robust to lighting changes.

Read up on the Hough Line Transform in openCV to get started.

Addendum:

Black to White is the strongest edge you can have. If you create a gradient image and use the strongest edges found in the scene (via histogram or other) you will be able to limit the detection to only the black/white edges. Look for intersections. This should give you a small number of center points to apply Hough ellipse detection (or alternate) to. You could rotate in a template as a further check if you wish.

BTW.. OpenCV has Edge Detection, Hough transform and FitEllipse if you do go down this route.

Comment: Hi - thank you for this answer -  the link doesn't help me completly but it seems very helpful and i will read it closely. Hough Line Transform could be possible but there will be other lines cause of surounding objects. But i will look at this more closely too. Anyway thank you for those fast answeres. If any more ideas - i am realy grateful.

Answer (score 1):

actually this 'pizza' pattern is one of the building blocks of the haar featured used in the 
[Viola–Jones object detection framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework).

So what I would do is compute the summed area table, or integral image using `cv::integral(img)` and then run exhaustive search for this pattern, on various scales (size dependant).
In each window you are using only 9 points (top-left, top-center, ..., bottom left).

Comment: Thanks for you post but i couldn't get out much of this. Because i didn't realy understand the math behind this framework and i tried integral for 5 min and couldn't figure out how I could use it. I solved it now. So thank you a lot for your post.